# hubot-slack with js - how to handle several questions with only one command?

Tags: javascript, prompt, hubot, slack-api

I am making hubot-slack just for fun.

The thing I want to implement is let hubot get several questions at once. For instance, like below:

```
user : @hubot: add job 
hubot : what is your job ? 
user : jobless 
hubot : where is your workplace ? 
user : home 
hubot : your job has registered.
```

As you can see, user will trigger event only once with command `add job`.
So following is my javascript source to handle it.

Calling part :

```
robot.respond(/register me/igm, function(msg){
    //var promptConsole = new Prompt(msg);
    var questions = [
        {'question' : 'What is your name ?', 'dataname' : 'name'}
        , {'question' : 'What is your job ?', 'dataname' : 'job'}
    ];
    var promptConsole = new Prompt(msg, questions);
    promptConsole.init().startPrompt(robot);
});
```

and Prompt Object :

```
var Prompt = function (msg, questions) {

    console.log(msg);
    this.msg = msg;
    this.user = msg.message.user;
    this.room = msg.message.room;
    this.results;
    this.questions = questions;

    //console.log(user +' is in room [ ' + room + ' ] ');

    this.init = function () {
        this.results = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < questions.length; i ++) {
            var singleQuestion = questions[i];
            var result = {'key': '', 'question' : '', 'value' : ''};
            result.key = singleQuestion.dataname;
            result.question = singleQuestion.question;
            this.results.push(result);
        }
        return this;
    }

    this.startPrompt = function () {
        for(var i = 0; i < this.results.length; i ++) {
            console.log(this.results[i]);
            this.msg.send(this.results[i].question);
        }
    }
}
```

However, this function can not be implemented with `robot.hear` or `robot.respond`, since user input happens only once.

Is there any other way to implement this? If not, I should separate this function to many part like `add job`, `add workplace` and so on.